# What is the maximum number of subnets that can be assigned to a single VLAN?

Tags: vlan

When configuring a VLAN in SVI (Switch Virtual Interface) in layer 3 switch, what is the maximum number of subnets that can be assigned to a single VLAN?

Comment: Maybe research over on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have asked two questions:

1. How many subnets can exist simultaneously on a VLAN.

Unlimited for IPV4 and Single(not counting local addresses) for IPV6 using SLAAC, unlimited for manually assigned and DHCP.

2. How many subnets can be used with layer 3 switching?

Only a single route-able address is permitted per protocol(IPV4 and IPV6) to be assigned to the VLAN interface.  This is based on Cisco devices, other vendors may have different requirements.

Comment: I have heard that multiple secondary IP addresses can be assigned to a single VLAN interface, in addition to the primary IP address of the same interface, is that true?

Comment: @Dilki, On routers, you can have a secondary IPv4 address assigned to an interface.